# How to find all entries in SVN repo with an external to a given URL

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [List all svn:externals recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681833/list-all-svnexternals-recursively)

I need to move the location of a component that is referenced by many projects with an `svn:external`.

How can I easily find all locations that have an `svn:external` to this URI?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681833/list-all-svnexternals-recursively and http://superuser.com/questions/191864/viewing-all-subversion-externals

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
 svn propget svn:externals http://path/to/repos -R
```

lists all externals, its not filtered, suppose i could grep it if i was on a decent OS.

Answer (score 6):

I used a slight variation on the other answer (apologies for partial plagiarism)...

```
svn propget --xml -R svn:externals https://myserver/myrepo > results.xml
```

and then ran the results through an XPath using something like...

```
//properties/target[contains(./property,'https://myserver/myrepo/mysearchpath')]/@path
```

This gave me a short list containing all references.

The longest part was waiting for the propget which takes *literally* hours on our repository.  Not sure if this can be improved.

Comment: The command given searches a complete repository, which is slow. Maybe it is sufficient to search the externals referenced in your working copies? Then a similar command is **much** faster:
`svn propget svn:externals --xml -R * > results.xml`

Comment: I agree @SomeStupid, although that only works if the working copy contains the referencing (not referenced) code.  Since it was mentioned that the author had many projects referencing the external, I assumed that it was not known which projects referenced it, but a working copy search is far faster if you do know!