# Git SVN and externals

Tags: svn, git, git-svn

I want to start use git-svn for a projects which uses a central SVN repository. The problem is that we are using windows and that the SVN project uses externals in order to be able to reuse some code in two different projects. In a Unix system we would have used soft links but since we are stuck with windows we decided to go with externals as a workaround for the limitations in windows xp. If you have a better solution for this a would be more than happy to hear that! The svn structure is as follows:

```
branch
tag
trunk
 -web
  --views
     ---External to commonFiles
-admin
  --views
    ---External to commonFiles
-commonFiles
```

Is it possible for me to be able to use git-svn and if so how can I do it?

***Edit***
I have been searching for good solution for a long time now but after writing this post I started to think how much this actually has to do with svn:externals. If I use git svn I will get this

```
branch
tag
trunk
 -web
  --views
     ---commonFiles (empty folder since externals didn't work)
-admin
  --views
    ---commonFiles (empty folder since externals didn't work)
-commonFiles
```

Since I have the commonFiles folder in git, can I use the same technique as in svn in git? To link the empty commonFiles folders to the commonFiles that are maintained with git?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have now come up with a solution which a works great for me! I found out that it is possible to use something called junctions in windows xp. Junctions are something similar to mount with the difference that if you remove a folder the other folder also will get removed. So what I ended up doing is to to create junctions between my commonFiles folders and add ignores to the folders withing the views.

```
branch
tag
trunk
 -web
  --views
     ---commonFiles (junction to *, ignored in git)
-admin
  --views
    ---commonFiles (junction to *, ignored in git)
-commonFiles (*, controlled by git)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should be able to have a git equivelant via git submodule. A .git folder and a .gitmodules file would exist in at the same level as web and admin checks out to. A .git folder would exist in the External folder. You would want to ignore .svn folders in git and vice versa for svn.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Do you mean that I should use git without git-svn? To use git and svn on the same working copy?

Comment: No, you would still have git-svn usage. But you would be able to run a whole bunch of tooling that is only available in git as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

You can try having [detached worktrees](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=105022) with multiple repos and then use the [mr tool](http://kitenet.net/~joey/code/mr/). To facilitate the work with multiple repos.

Comment: The asker is on windows. Their solution involved reinventing symlinks; they don't have access to tools like mr.

Answer (score 0):

As unkownt suggests junctions is a good option.

When you check out the source tree will look like this:

```
branch
tag
trunk
 -web
  --views
-admin
  --views
-commonFiles
```

The externals have been omitted.
To [get the list of externals](https://stackoverflow.com/a/682287/1575281) you can use the following command on an existing repository:

```
svn propget svn:externals -R
```

For relative externals (those starting with ..) this is simple. You can use mklink to create a junction. In this example run the following commands:

```
mklink /J trunk\web\views\commonFiles trunk\commonFiles
mklink /J trunk\admin\views\commonFiles trunk\commonFiles
```

You could add these commands to a git-hook to ensure that they are create on check out.