# how to get "green" (i.e. nothing to commit) on the entire solution in VisualSVN

Tags: tortoisesvn, visualsvn

I'm using VisualSVN and VS

All projects in my Solution has "green" circle meaning that there is nothing to commit
However entire solution has "yellow" circle.

tortoisesvn says that only one **folder** is changed, the status of this folder is "modified (property change only)"

It also says that "Working base" of this folder is empty and "Working copy" is:

```
*.suo
*.ncb
*.sdf
*.opensdf
ipch
*.user
_ReSharper.*
Myproject
```

I don't understand what's going on.
How is that possible that **folder itself** has some content that can be changed and compared and commited?
I mean folder is just a container for files and other folders, isn't it?

Should I commit this change? Should it be versioned? What is that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property change only means that the svn metadata on a folder has changed.  If you look carefully, probably all of those changes are coming from the svn:ignore property, which tells subversion not to consider those files versioned.

Other examples of metadata include svn merge tracking and svn:externals (for example [List all svn:externals recursively?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/681833/list-all-svnexternals-recursively))

Whether or not to commit metadata is the same as any other change, does it do what you want?  I would guess that in this case, Resharper (or some other tool) is adding that metadata automatically.

Since you are using tortoise svn, you can view the metadata on the folder by right clicking the folder -> properties -> Subversion -> Properties

See also http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.advanced.props.html for a more full explanation of svn properties.

Comment: thanks, right, in properties i see "svn:ignore" does it mean that I should rollback the change? I either need to commit it, rollback or unversion file...

Comment: I would probably commit it.  Most of what I see in your list is pretty standard stuff to ignore, which means subversion won't commit it.  For example, .suo files are user specific visual studio files, and you almost never want to commit those, especially on a multi-dev team. Same for .user and resharper files.  If you want to ignore some and not others, you can edit the svn:ignore property before committing.